# "Signal Over Range!!" and grub/update doesn't fix

Tags: boot

- `3.19.0-26-generic #28-Ubuntu  T`
- `01:05.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS880 [Radeon HD 4200]`
- Hercules ProphetView monitor

This is a server, with no x-windows or gui. There's no dual-boot, or anything like that.

On boot I get the grub screen, then some boot messages, and then right after the hard drive messages the monitor switches to "Signal Over Range!!"

Editing `/etc/default/grub` and then doing a `sudo update-grub` doesn't seem to have any effect.

Grub config below (with "normal" comments removed):

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=false
GRUB_TIMEOUT=3
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="radeon.modeset=1"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"
GRUB_TERMINAL=console
GRUB_GFXMODE=1024x768
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

The `radeon.modeset` is something new I tried this morning. It doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Some quick googling indicates that your monitors native resolution is 1024 x 768 at 75 Hz , so that seems right as far as it goes, I think you also need to choose bits per pixel as in say 1024x768x32... You may find this a useful source of information: http://askubuntu.com/questions/18444/how-do-i-increase-console-mode-resolution based on the error however it sounds like the frquency range doesn't match your monitor.

Comment: adding depth (x32) had no impact. I'll check the thread you refer to to.

Comment: `vbeinfo` as referred to in the thread I mentioned may prove useful as well as https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/gfxpayload.html which you could change to text which would seem fine on  a server IMHO

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/52910/signal-out-of-range-when-starting-grub-after-server-installation

Comment: Could you attach, say, another monitor to determine which frequencies (refresh and scan) does the video output have? Is there a valid video signal at all?

Answer (score 0):

You might try this:

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=1024x768x32
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep
```

Other related info can be found below:

- [What exactly does GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=text do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61233/what-does-grub-setting-grub-gfxpayload-linux-text)
- [GRUB Simple configuration](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/Simple-configuration.html#Simple-configuration)
- [GRUB Tips and tricks](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB/Tips_and_tricks)
- [“signal out of range” when starting grub after server installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52910/signal-out-of-range-when-starting-grub-after-server-installation)